# knockout change event function

Tags: javascript, csv, knockout.js

Trying to upload multiple csv files using a knockout change event. Initially the change function works and the values get written to the viewmodel.  The problem is when trying to upload a second csv file the knockout change event doesn't fire. Is there a way to get the change function to re-fire after the first time?

```
<input id="uploadFile" type="file" multiple="multiple" data-bind="event: { change: PO.fileUploadChange }"/>

export function fileUploadChange(data, evt): void {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(evt.target.files, function (file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = LoadCSVData;

        reader.readAsText(evt.target.files.item(0))
        model.quickEntryModel.files.push(evt.target.files.item(0));

        var input = document.getElementById('uploadFile');
        if (input != null)
            document.getElementById('uploadFile').outerHTML = input.outerHTML;
    })


}
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with the last line. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but I'm assuming you're clearing the input. You should move it outside the `arrayForEach` loop:

```
export function fileUploadChange(data, evt): void {
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(evt.target.files, function (file) {

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = LoadCSVData;

        reader.readAsText(evt.target.files.item(0))
        model.quickEntryModel.files.push(evt.target.files.item(0));
    });

    var input = document.getElementById('uploadFile');
    if (input != null)
        input.value = "";
}
```

[Here's a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/adigas/xsyuz4ss/2/)